# How to add a custom field to Address Compound Field on Account

Tags: custom-field, account, ui, address, compound-fields

Requirement: Add a custom field to the address compound field on the account object.

Salesforce provides a street, city, state, state code, country, country code and zip code in the address field. I have to add a new field called District.

Is there any possibility to add a custom field?

Though I can able to rename the field label of State code and Country Code I don't know why these fields are not visible on UI.

Will it be possible to make them visible on UI and change the type of State code and Country Code field so that I can capture the District Information.

Comment: You can add a custom field to the object. You cannot make your own compound Address or Address-like field or customize an out of the box compound Address field. Vote for this idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DjHlAAK